# Options for fixing or working around a bent pin on a laptop monitor connector?

Tags: laptop, display, connector

I was cleaning out my laptop, when the ribbon connecting the screen to the motherboard came loose, When reconnecting it, I bent 2 of the pins on the connector on the motherboard (doh!).

Everything still works fine except obviously the screen (I'm using an external monitor).

What options have I? Seems to me, I can either try to bend the pin back straight (risking snapping it off entirely, and I don't know how I'd GET it perfectly straight), or replace the motherboard (bah!).

**Do I have any other options than replacing my motherboard?**

I don't think I do, but I wanted to ask to be safe before I go trying to bend pins back. Any tips on how to straighten them?

Presumably I can't claim on my warranty after this.

I'm not sure what the connector type is actually called, the best picture I can find is this:

[image]

This is a Samsung r560 laptop.

**Edit**: Two of them have entirely snapped off now, with 3 other bent ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to get the pins perfectly straight. If you can get them straight enough there might be enough leeway in the socket to *gently* force it over the bent pins which will straighten them some more.

As to how to get them more or less straight - use the finest pliers you have or a pair of tweezers.

Comment: I agree and would add that bend the pins a little at a time in stages. When you bend metal it gets hot and could break. (Kind of like if you twisted a paperclip 180 degrees all at once quickly vice bending it a little beyond it's bounce back point.) In the past (with HD connectors) I would bend the pins back slowly enough to get the connector on those pins, then I used the ribbon plug to align those pins with the rest, slowly. Fixing pins is a slow and patient art. For the HD connector I used a knife because I could use the tip of the blade at the base of the pin and leverage the whole pin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do the bending in a warm place. Cold metal is brittle and more likely to snap.